# How to specify a validation rule in Yii2 which will be greater than or less than of a specific number or value?

Tags: model, yii2, validationrules

I have a model with a validation rule like:

```
[['x'], 'integer'],
[['x'], 'unique'],
```

Now how can I add a rule like:

> x < 100 
>   or something like 
>  x >= 100

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be:

```
['x', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 100, 'operator' => '<'],
```

and

```
['x', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 100, 'operator' => '>='],
```

accordingly.

Read more in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#compare).

Comment: Ehh)) You are faster)))

Comment: Hi @arogachev : How can we give message on this ? I gave `['x', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 100, 'operator' => '>=' , 'message'=>'Hi To all'],`. But not working. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `min` attribute on number, or integer validators:

```
['age', 'integer', 'min' => 0],
['amount', 'number', 'min' => 0],
```

There is also a `max` option.

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 greater than validation :

**field_to must be greater than "field_from".**

Field 1 : field_from

Field 2 : field_to

```
[['field_to'], 'compare', 'when' => function($model) {
                        return $model->builtup_area != null;
                    }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value){
                    return $('#form-field_from').val() != '';
                }", 'compareAttribute' => 'field_from', 'operator' => '>', 'type' => 'number'],
```