# Validation in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want that my **quantity**[*field name*] must be **zero(0**) or **positive**

I define following rules in my model.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['quantity'], 'integer', 'min' => 0],
        [['quantity'], 'integer', 'max' => 1000000],

    ];
}
```

And it is **working properly**. And display error message  when i try to enter *negative value*  .

> But The **Problem** is it accept **-0** [ **minus zero** ]

How to restrict user to do not enter **-0** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, nothing strange since `-0` is equal to `0`, you could simply use a match rule :

```
['quantity', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[0-9]*$/'],
['quantity', 'integer', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 1000000],
```

Read more about [`match` validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#match).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
['quantity', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 0, 'operator' => '>='],
```

for more details, you can have a look at [How to specify a validation rule in Yii2 which will be greater than or less than of a specific number or value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362069/how-to-specify-a-validation-rule-in-yii2-which-will-be-greater-than-or-less-than)